# Launching JSF dialog conditionally

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

How can I launch a dialog according to some conditions? I am using primefaces components.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`RequestContext` provides a useful API to pass parameters from JSF backing beans in json format to ajax callbacks like `oncomplete`. Execute javascript from server side and add components to update programmatically.

An example of code for Backend Bean:

```
RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();

if (condition)
{
    context.addCallbackParam("someVariable", true);
}
else
{
    context.addCallbackParam("someVariable", false);
}
```

We wand to write a `javaScript` function in the frontend (xhtml ) to handle this callback,like this

```
function precautionsDialogShow(xhr, status, args)
{
    if(args.someVariable)
    {
        dialogue.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

With 3.x, RequestContext also provides an easier api called execute.

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("dialogue.show()");
```

Comment: so with PF 5 this would be like: RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("PF('dialogName').show()"); ?